# How to disable COMPLETLY all updates?

Tags: updates

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and I want to disable all updates for ever.  The choices in the software updates do not offer NEVER in all options.  I dont want to SHOW that there are update available. Nothing.

I want to install this in my in-laws and they are too old to deal with that.  I always have to connect and take care of their system (right now with Windows but wants to install Ubuntu).

I see in the questions asked, that older versions had that choice available.  Can I change this in a file somewhere?

Comment: It is safer to enable automatic updates than disable all updates.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Disabling all updates is the wrong approach for your REAL problem ("*The users don't understand*")

Answer (score 4):

Disabling *all* updates will require you to remove all of the references for `apt` and also tell `snapd` to not perform any updates. Aside from the security implications that would come from running software that never receives any bug-fixes, this would effectively eliminate your in-laws' ability to install applications from the Software Centre.

However, if you are dead-set on eliminating updates, this is how you would do it:

1. Open the Software & Updates application
2. Uncheck everything in "Ubuntu Software":
   [image: Ubuntu Software]
3. Uncheck everything in "Other Software":
   [image: Other Software]
4. Block `snapd` from accessing the Snap Store API:

   1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
   2. Edit the `/etc/hosts` file with your text editor of choice. Be sure to prefix the command with `sudo`:

      ```
      sudo vi /etc/hosts
      ```
   3. Add this line under the IPv4 section:

      ```
      127.0.0.1 api.snapcraft.io
      ```
   4. Save the file

By doing this, Ubuntu will be unable to check for updates on its own. However, note that this will not stop applications such as Chrome from doing their own updates. These can be controlled by the application and operate outside the typical update process.

One final note; be sure to undo all of these changes and perform updates whenever you go and visit your in-laws. Updates are offered for a reason, and an unpatched system — even one that is running Linux — is not something that should be connected to the open Internet anymore.

Comment: *Chrome from doing their own updates* -- Does it not add a new repository, which can also be unchecked in the other software tab? I have not used Chrome for a few years, I don't know if the update mechanism changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: I, too, have not used Chrome in a few years on a Linux system. On Windows and macOS the updates are handled outside of the standard mechanism, though. I would assume Google would do the same sly thing on Linux just for consistency's sake. I could be completely wrong, though ...

Comment: Yes, in Windows and Mac there are automatic background updates, but in Ubuntu it used to add a repository to `sources.list`. Anyway, nice answer. +1.

Comment: Chrome still adds its own repo, at least in 18.04. I added it to my local mirror because everyone on the LAN uses Chrome.

Comment: @matigo "On Windows and macOS the updates are handled outside of the standard mechanism" - because (at least on Windows, I don't know about Mac) there simply is **no** "standard mechanism". Windows is doing their own updates only and each application is doing their own. There are no repositories from where you can install software by default like in Linux.

Comment: Ha.... Thank you so much guys... you made my day.  PS:  My in-laws uses their computer only for skype as a "phone" . Absolutly nothing else, so I'm not worry disabling the updates.  Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how it is in 21.04, but in 20.04 I have five drop-down fields in the "Updates" tab. The second one defines how often the system should check for updates, and there is option "Never" at the end. **I guess** (haven't tried it), that setting  this option, together with setting the action for both security updates (3rd field) and other updates (4th field) to "notify only" should effectively disable updates - except snap updates, they are always installed automatically because it's just how `snapd` works. Has this option been removed in 21.04 ?